# Granting permission in ArcSDE geodatabasewhen layers are inside geometric network?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, authentication

When I use sdetable command to grant pemission to a table that located in a SDE SQL server geodatabase it works properly, this table is a non-spatial table which is in geodatabase immediately, I mean when I open geodatabase in ArcCatalog, I can see it in the root of geodatabase.

But we have a FeatureDataset named "dsDisNet" and almost all feature classes inside in this feature dataset are members of a geometric network(except one).When I use sdelayer command to grant permission for one feature class, it is done successfully but the user can't still update the table.

Here is steps I do:

1. define a login in SQL Server, then define a user in geodatabase mapped to login
2. give the data_reader role to this user, so user can see all layers successfully
3. run this command

   sdetable -o grant -t myTable -U gisUser1 -A SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE -s GISServer -i 5151 -D GDBase -u sa -p mypassword

and it works successfully, and this user can work with that table

4. sdelayer -o grant -l myLayer,Shape -U gisUser1 -A SELECT,UPDATE -s GISServer -i 5151 -D GDBase -u sa -p mypassword

this last command doesn't work properly even it is run successfully,but the user still receive this message in ArcMap (something like this "cannot edit the folder or database you selected, the user doesn't have enough permission"

Is this problem because the layer is inside a feature dataset or member of geometric network? If so, how I can give update permission for this layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ArcCatalog and in this case you need to grant the permissions **on the feature dataset** in which the network resides, not its individual feature classes.

Note that it's not the geometric network (or topology etc.) which dictates this approach, it's the presence of a feature dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much,but when I use privilege menu to grant permission for feature dataset to a user, all feature classes inside feature dataset will be updatable by that user,but I want he/she can update only one feature class in that feature dataset,is there any way to reach this type of permission?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not. Once you group feature classes under a feature dataset, that dataset essentialy becomes a single unit on which you set permissions. I have never quite understood why ESRI chose this design, to be honest. I know that you need to have the dataset so that a geometric network can be created, but my advice would be to keep only the network classes in the dataset and put everyhing else somewhere separate, i.e. in the root or another dataset.

Comment: Having the same set of permissions on all the classes of a geometric network should not be a major limitation. Quite the opposite - I think it's more than recommended to keep permissions of the whole geometric network consistent so that no problems arise during editing.